# What are the advantages of Cons?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

Many *functional* programming languages support and recommend the data constructor `Cons` (for lists like `(1, (2, (3)))`, such as [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) and [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List).

But what are its advantages? Such lists can neither be randomly accessed, nor be appended to in `O(1)`.

Comment: Advantages over what, exactly? Normally when you talk about advantages, they are over and above some alternative method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Cons` (a shorthand for "construct") is not a data structure, it's the name of the *operation* for creating a *cons-cell* . And by linking together several cells a data structure can be built, in particular - a linked list. The rest of the discussion assumes that a linked list is being created with `cons` operations.

Although it's possible to append in O(1) at the head, accessing elements randomly by index is a costly operation, that requires the traversal of all the elements before the one that's being accessed.

The advantages of a linked list? it's a *functional* data structure, cheap to create or recreate in case of modifications; it allows sharing of nodes between several lists and it allows easy garbage collection. It's very flexible, with correct abstractions it's possible to represent other, more complex data structures such as stacks, queues, trees, graphs. And there are many, many procedures written specifically for manipulating lists - for instance `map`, `filter`, `fold`, etc. that make working with lists a joy. Finally, a list is a *recursive* data structure, and recursion (specially tail recursion) is the preferred way to solve problems in functional programming languages; so in these languages it's natural to have a recursive data structure as the main data structure.

Comment: Actually, the OP seems to be using "cons" in a way typical in the ML tradition of functional programming, where the term "data constructor" would be correct. In that context, the data constructor simultaneously serves as the definition of a "cons cell", the operation that creates one, and the pattern used to extract the head and tail of an existing list. Also, in these languages it is usually exclusive to lists, rather than the all-purpose building block cons cells are in lisps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's distinguish between "cons" as a nickname for the ML-style list data constructor usually called `::` and what the nickname comes from, the original Lisp-style `cons` function.

In Lisps, cons cells are an all-purpose data structure not restricted to lists of homogeneous element type. The equivalent in ML-style languages would be nested pairs or 2-tuples, with the empty list represented by the "unit" type often written `()`. Óscar López gives a good overview of the utility of the Lisp `cons`, so I'll leave it at that.

In most ML-style languages the advantages of immutable cons lists are not too different from their use for lists in Lisps, trading off the flexibility of dynamic typing for the guarantees of static typing and the syntax of ML-style pattern matching.

In Haskell, however, the situation is rather different due to lazy evaluation. Constructors are lazy and pattern matching on them is one of the few ways to force evaluation, so in contrast to strictly-evaluated languages it is often the case that you should *avoid* tail recursion. Instead, by placing the recursive call in the tail of a list it becomes possible to compute each recursive call only when needed. If a lazily-generated list is processed with appropriately lazy functions like `map` or `foldr`, it becomes possible to construct and consume a large list in constant memory, with the tails being forced at the same rate the heads are abandoned for the GC to clean up.

A common perspective in Haskell is that a lazy cons list is not so much a data structure as it is a *control* structure--a reified loop that composes efficiently with other such loops.

That said, there are many cases where a cons list is *not* appropriate--such as when repeated random access is needed--and in those situations using lists is certainly not recommended.